# A list of the organizations accredited to run projects under European Voluntary Service

Tags: data-request, companies, database

I need a list of the organizations accredited to run projects under European Voluntary Service.

See: http://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/evs-organisation_en
EVS accredited organisations search results: 6073

See also https://europa.eu/youth/volunteering_en

This lists the organisations accredited to run projects under European Voluntary Service - part of the European Union's Erasmus+ programme. We recommend that you first use the database of volunteering projects to find  projects that you might be interested in.

How to get the list of the accredited EVS organisation, that run volunteering projects?

Comment: Have you tried reaching to the European Youth Portal with request for that information? They seem to be pretty open and communicative.